# Comparing strings in a List of reference types

Tags: c#

I have Implemented code in C# that compares 2 strings character by character and returns the percentage difference between the 2 strings. Below is the code.

```
public static double percentage(string a, string b)
    {  
        double percent;

        if (a == b) //Same string, no iteration needed.
            percent = 100;
        if ((a.Length == 0) || (b.Length == 0)) //One is empty, second is not
        {
            percent = 0;
        }
        double maxLen = a.Length > b.Length ? a.Length : b.Length;
        int minLen = a.Length < b.Length ? a.Length : b.Length;
        int sameCharAtIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < minLen; i++) //Compare char by char
        {
            if (a[i] == b[i])
            {
                sameCharAtIndex++;
            }
        }
        percent = sameCharAtIndex / maxLen * 100;
        Console.WriteLine("Difference {0}", percent.ToString());
        return percent;
      }
```

I have fetched data from 2 tables in my database and stored the data in 2 lists as below

```
                //ListOfPerson
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    //var person = new Person();
                    person.ID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]);
                    person.firstName = reader["FirstName"].ToString();
                    person.middleName = reader["MiddleName"].ToString();
                    person.lastName = reader["LastName"].ToString();

                    ListOfPerson.Add(person);
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2} {3}", person.ID, person.firstName, person.middleName, person.lastName);
                } 


                //ListOfEmployee
                while (reader1.Read())
                {
                    //var employee = new Employee();

                    employee.firstName = reader1["FirstName"].ToString();
                    employee.lastName = reader1["LastName"].ToString();

                    ListOfEmployee.Add(employee);

                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", employee.firstName, employee.lastName);
                }
```

I want to compare person.firstName (in the entire ListOfPerson)and employee.firstName (in the entire ListOfEmployee) character by character and get the percentage.
I have tried doing this :

```
               foreach (var p in ListOfPerson)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < ListOfEmployee.Count(); i++)
                    {
                        clsCompare.percentage(p.firstName, ListOfEmployee[i].firstName);
                    }
                }
```

but its only looping through the last name in ListOfPerson and ListOfEmployee. How can i achieve this? looping through all the names comparing character by character in the 2 Lists.

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried stepping through with breakpoints or writing out the names too?The code you have looks like it should iterate through all

Comment: While it should iterate through, how are you capturing the return value of `clsCompare.percentage(...)`?

Comment: Why is `var person = new Person();` commented? Without `new Person()` you are just making a list containing same persons. That is why you only get the last person.

Comment: @Sayse I have stepped through the code several times and its only getting the last names in each list. I dont understand why..

Comment: i think this is better: `double maxLen = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);` and `int minLen = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);`

Comment: @bokibeg i have declared it globally, so that i can use it in other parts of the code

Comment: @Lawrence - thats a different issue that bokibeg's comment has the answer for. Edit: Also, in general, make a variable's scope as small as possible

Comment: Have you stepped through and confirmed that both your lists have the values you'd expect in them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is incorrect. Add return statements like this:

```
if (a == b) //Same string, no iteration needed.
    return percent = 100;
if ((a.Length == 0) || (b.Length == 0)) //One is empty, second is not
{
    return percent = 0;
}
```

The `new` statements are required. You have marked them as comments. Without the `new` statements, you are not allocating any new memory for the new values. You are saving all the values in the same object thus overwriting the previous values.

You also need to do something with the returned value. You are just calling the function. You should probably store that value in a variable or print it.